# Flot Share Tooltips

Tags: jquery, flot

Using Flot to dynamically graph multiple series. Using Toottips to provide labels on hover. Where multiple series have the same points on the grid, Tooltips displays label from only 1 series. Would like to have Tooltips display shared labels with each series on the point showing its label.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe this ability readily exists.  I would pre-screen my data and make a note of any overlapping data points.  The viability of this approach, of course, depends on the size of you datasets:

```
var data1 = [[0,3],[1,1],[2,2],[4,8],[5,10]];
var data2 = [[0,2],[1,2],[2,2],[4,6],[6,13]];

overLap = {}

for (var i = 0; i < data1.length; ++i)
{
    for (var j = 0; j < data2.length; ++j)
    {
        if ((data1[i][0] == data2[j][0]) && (data1[i][1] == data2[j][1]))
            overLap[data1[i]] = "label1 and label2";
    }
}
```

Then on the plothover just check your overLap associate array:

```
$("#placeholder").bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {
        if (item) {   
          var key = [item.datapoint[0], item.datapoint[1]]
          if(key in overLap)
          {
               alert(overLap[key]);
          }
        }              
});
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z8xpn/) with a working example.